# How to convert formula to disjunctive normal form?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus, disjunctive-normal-form

> Convert
>
> $$((p \wedge q) → r) \wedge (¬(p \wedge q) → r)$$
>
> to DNF.

This is what I've already done:

$$((p \wedge q) → r) \wedge (¬(p \wedge q) → r)$$

$$(¬(p \wedge q) \vee r) \wedge ((p \wedge q) \vee r)$$

$$((¬p \vee ¬q) \vee r) \wedge ((p \wedge q) \vee r)$$

And from this point I'm not sure how to proceed. Help would be appreciated.

Sorry, but the last line was written badly (I think). It's fixed now.

Comment: It's really great you got as far as you did; thanks for showing what you've done.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can continue by using [Distributivity of the boolean algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_%28logic%29):

$((¬p \vee ¬q) \vee r) \wedge ((p \wedge q) \vee r)$

$ \Leftrightarrow (¬p \vee ¬q \vee r) \wedge ((p \wedge q) \vee r)$

Here we apply distributivity:

$ \Leftrightarrow (¬p \wedge p \wedge q) \vee (¬q \wedge p \wedge q) \vee (r \wedge p \wedge q) \vee (¬p \wedge r) \vee (¬q \wedge r) \vee (r \wedge r)$

Formally, this is in disjunctive normal form now.
We could further simplify:

$ \Leftrightarrow (r \wedge p \wedge q) \vee (¬p \wedge r) \vee (¬q \wedge r) \vee r$

Comment: Sorry for asking, but how did you use distributivity law to get the third line? All I can think of is to use this identity:
a∧(b∨c)=(a∧b)∨(a∧c) to get this:
((¬p∨¬q∨r)∧(p∧q))∨((¬p∨¬q∨r)∧r)

Comment: Here you use: (a∨b∨c)∧(d∨e)=(a∧d)∨(b∧d)∨(c∧d)∨(a∧e)∨(b∧e)∨(c∧e)

Comment: The above can be seen as follows: (a∨b∨c)∧(d∨e) = ((a∨b∨c)∧d) ∨ ((a∨b∨c)∧e) = (a∧d)∨(b∧d)∨(c∧d)∨(a∧e)∨(b∧e)∨(c∧e)

Comment: brother, how did you simplified further the last statement using disjunctive normal form

Answer (score 1):

$$((p \land q) \to r) \land (\neg(p \land q)\to r) \equiv (\neg(p \land q) \lor r) \land ((p \land q) \lor r)$$

using the distributive law

$$r \lor (\neg (p \land q) \land (p \land q)) \equiv r \lor \text{False} \equiv r$$

because $s \land \neg s \equiv \text{False}$.