# Simplifying the Boolean expression $\overline{(a+b)\cdot \overline{a(b\oplus c)}}$ to have lowest number of logical gates

Tags: boolean-algebra, boolean

I have this boolean expression
$$
f(a,b,c)_{Question}=nand(or(a,b) , nand(a, xor(b,c)))    = \overline{(a+b)\cdot \overline{a(b\oplus c)}}
$$
when I try to simplify the gates using boolean algebra, I get
$$
f(a,b,c)_{Question}=or(nor(a,b) , and(a,xor(b,c)))=\overline{a+b}+(a\cdot(b⊕c))
$$

***I need to simplify further and get***
$$  
f(a,b,c)_{answer}=a\oplus(b \oplus \overline{a\cdot c})
$$
my function: $f_{answer}$ is justified by the criteria:

- $f_{answer}$ uses lowest number of logical gates,(in our case minimum:3(xor,xor,and))
- there may be *n* number of possible $f_{answer}$, example we can have another answer with same-minimum number of logical gates: $(a\oplus b) \oplus \overline{a\cdot c}$ is another possible answer,to our function,and it will be accepted,since it has only 3 logical gates,its is accepted

**Question:** So how can I find $f_{answer}$ when $f_{Question}$ is provided, what are the steps

but don't know what's the *****steps******,can anyone help?

I found these rules for xor:
[image]
from [here](http://pubs.sciepub.com/jcsa/1/1/3/index.html) but they are of no use

#### Edit:

when I ***expand***** $
f(a,b,c)_{Question}=\overline{a+b}+a\cdot(b⊕c)
$
I get
$$
f(a,b,c)_{expanded}=\overline{(\overline{\overline{a}\overline{b}})\cdot (\overline{a\cdot\overline{\overline{b}\overline{c}}\cdot \overline{bc}})}
$$

**The process to simplify,like "first remove brackets...",*  ***"Steps" is the answer I need for this question***

***Which I think would be the first step in converting any, $f_{Question}$ to $f_{answer}$*

Comment: What does "a xor (b,c)" mean, which appears just after your f(a,b,c) as part of the definition of f? [I would think xor is a binary connective, so should only appear between two boolean expressions, but I don't think (b,c) counts as a boolean expression,]

Comment: sorry for confusion,i mean *xor(b,c)* as *b xor c* and its not "a xor (b,c)",its "nand(a, xor (b,c))" which means *!(a*(b xor c))*, i think words may confuse,but you can understand the equation on right which uses symbols I guess

Comment: Can you replace $b \oplus c$ by (b bar(c))+(bar(b) c)$ ? Here I mean by bar(x) to have x with a bar over it.

Comment: I simply mean to ask what I mentioned in my comment, unrelated to its application in your problem. In other words I'm asking whether my guess is right for a definition of $b \oplus c$ all in terms of just $\cdot,\ +,\ (overbar).$

Comment: yes its right,as well as i will use mostly *b xor c* as $\overline{\overline{b}\overline{c}} \cdot \overline{bc}$, its how i solved.but final result need to be $f(a,b,c)_{answer}=a\oplus(b \oplus \overline{ac})
$ (both f0 and answer is same,i only don't know how to solve)

Comment: Suppose you change all things of form $x \oplus y$ to either the version in your comment above or the (to me) simpler version I asked about. What I mean is change both the simplified thing you're aiming for as well as the starting boolean expression. If you do so, then after that you won't need to use *any* rules about $x \oplus y$ to prove the equivalence you want. [Of course in converting away all the $\oplus$ it may result in very complicated looking expressions, and perhaps if one knew more rules about $\oplus$ it would make things simpler.]

Comment: yes thats what I usually do,but this time I don't know how to convert the expanded form to the answer form, I will update the Q.S

Comment: What I meant was to also convert the answer form to get rid of the $\oplus$ that are in it. Then you just have two expressions without $\oplus$ to check are equivalent,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136648/discussion-between-neptotech-vishnu-and-coffeemath).

Answer (score 2):

More complex Boolean expression can be calculated using algebraic expressions for each gate.

In this system, we have

- $\operatorname{OR}(a,b) = a+b-ab$
- $\operatorname{AND}(a,b) = ab$
- $\operatorname{NOR}(a,b) = 1-a-b+ab$
- $\operatorname{NAND}(a,b) = 1-ab$
- $\operatorname{XOR}(a,b) = a+b-2ab$

with the usual rule that $a^2=a$.

In this case,  $or(nor(a,b) , and(a,xor(b,c)))$ becomes

$$1+ab-a-b+a(b+c-2bc)-(1+ab-a-b)(ab+ac-2abc)$$

$$=1+ab-a-b+ab+ac-2abc-ab-ac+2abc-ab-abc+2abc+ab+ac-2abc+ab+abc-2abc$$

$$=1+2ab-a-b+ac-2abc$$

And similarly, $a\oplus b\oplus\overline{ac}$ is represented by

$$(a+b-2ab)+(1-ac)-2(a+b-2ab)(1-ac)$$

$$=a+b-2ab+1-ac-2a-2b+4ab+2ac+2abc-4abc$$

$$=-a-b+2ab+1+ac-2abc$$

As the two last expressions in each case are the same, we can conclude that  $$or(nor(a,b) , and(a,xor(b,c)))=a\oplus b\oplus\overline{ac}$$.

Comment: oh,i know they are same,i need some steps to convert the equation,anyway something interesting!

Comment: can you explain how to turn back $1+2ab-a-b+ac-2abc$ to $a\oplus b\oplus\overline{ac}$

Comment: Do the same steps in reverse? It looks a bit artificial here though!

Comment: yes doing reverse will give the answer, but we can't know how to split terms and other stuffs,as the answer was only known,but not given. I should not split $2ab$ to $4ab-2ab$ without a reason(but I can do vice versa), as you say,it looks quite artificial, Is there no other way?

Comment: If you use truth tables, they are both $A'B'C'+A'B'C+AB'C+ABC'$, but reversing the process is again too contrived.

Comment: Even the SOP form is ok for me(its the actual q.s), If I was able to find a way to convert $A'B'C'+A'B'C+AB'C+ABC'$ to $a\oplus b\oplus\overline{ac}$, it will be fine

Comment: $A'B'C'+A'B'C+AB'C+ABC'=(A\oplus B)' \oplus AC$.

Comment: but i again repeat,*" that's not what i need."*

Answer (score 1):

The truth table for your expression is:

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}a&b&c&\overline{(a+b)\cdot\overline{a(b\oplus c)}}\\\hline  F&F&F&T\\F&F&T&T\\F&T&F&F\\F&T&T&F\\T&F&F&F\\T&F&T&T\\T&T&F&T\\T&T&T&F\end{array}$$

which means that it should be possible to convert your expression $f_{\text{Question}}$ into the [*disjunctive normal form*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) corresponding to this truth table, which is:

$$\overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c}+\overline{a}\overline{b}c+a\overline{b}c+ab\overline{c}$$

And, indeed:

$$\begin{array}{rcll}\overline{(a+b)\cdot\overline{a(b\oplus c)}}&=&\overline{(a+b)\cdot\overline{a(b\overline{c}+\overline{b}c)}}&\text{definition of }\oplus\\&=&\overline{(a+b)\cdot\overline{ab\overline{c}+a\overline{b}c}}&\text{distributivity}\\&=&\overline{(a+b)\cdot((\overline{a}+\overline{b}+c)\cdot(\overline{a}+b+\overline{c})})&\text{de Morgan's law}\\&=&\overline{a}\overline{b}+ab\overline{c}+a\overline{b}c&\text{de Morgan's law}\\&=&\overline{a}\overline{b}(\overline{c}+c)+ab\overline{c}+a\overline{b}c&\text{as }c+\overline{c}\text{ is true}\\&=&\overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c}+\overline{a}\overline{b}c+ab\overline{c}+a\overline{b}c&\text{distributivity}\\&=&\overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c}+\overline{a}\overline{b}c+a\overline{b}c+ab\overline{c}&\text{commutativity}\end{array}$$

Now, if $f_\text{Answer}$ is really an equivalent formula, it should result in the same truth table. This means that, similarly, you can convert $f_\text{Answer}$ to *the same* disjunctive normal form:

$$\begin{array}{rcll}a\oplus(b\oplus(\overline{ac}))&=&a\oplus(b\oplus(\overline{a}+\overline{c}))&\text{de Morgan's law}\\&=&a\oplus(b\oplus(\overline{a}+\overline{c}))&\text{de Morgan's law}\\&=&b\oplus(a\oplus(\overline{a}+\overline{c}))&\text{commutativity and associativity of }\oplus\\&=&b\oplus(a\cdot\overline{\overline{a}+\overline{c}}+\overline{a}(\overline{a}+\overline{c}))&\text{definition of }\oplus\\&=&b\oplus(aac+\overline{a}\overline{a}+\overline{a}\overline{c}))&\text{de Morgan's laws, distributivity}\\&=&b\oplus(\overline{a}+c)&\text{tidy up}\\&=&b\overline{\overline{a}+c}+\overline{b}(\overline{a}+c)&\text{definition of }\oplus\\&=&ba\overline{c}+\overline{b}\overline{a}+\overline{b}c&\text{de Morgan's law}\\&=&ab\overline{c}+\overline{a}\overline{b}(\overline{c}+c)+(\overline{a}+a)\overline{b}c&\overline{a}+a,\overline{c}+c\text{ are true}\\&=&ab\overline{c}+\overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c}+\overline{a}\overline{b}c+\overline{a}\overline{b}c+a\overline{b}c&\text{distributivity}\\&=&\overline{a}\overline{b}\overline{c}+\overline{a}\overline{b}c+a\overline{b}c+ab\overline{c}&\text{remove duplicates, commutativity}\end{array}$$

Phew! We've successfully transformed $f_\text{Question}$ and $f_\text{Answer}$ into their (common) disjunctive normal form, which means that we can now transform $f_\text{Question}$ into $f_\text{Answer}$ by first following the first transformation until reaching the disjunctive normal form, and then following the second transformation in reverse.

Of course, in the answer above, I mostly just applied the definition of $\oplus$ and well-known rules for $+$ and $\cdot$ (idempotency, commutativity, associativity, absorption, de Morgan's laws). Someone could come up with a longer or shorter proof. (In particular, a negation of a disjunctive normal form is a [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) and it takes quite a bit of work to convert it back to a disjunctive normal form. We were lucky to have two negations above!) However, the idea is the same:

- Either two expressions have the same truth table, in which case they have the same disjunctive normal form, and you can convert both to it - and therefore to each other,
- Or they don't have the same truth table, and obviously, being not equivalent, they cannot be converted to each other.

See also: [How to convert formula to disjunctive normal form?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/228969/how-to-convert-formula-to-disjunctive-normal-form)

Comment: You have shown, *steps to convert* Question to a Answer with lowest gate, but it's particular to this question only. ***What I really need is a general steps, that can be applied to any question,eg. $\overline{c}a+\overline{c}b$*** cannot have it's first step as definition of $\oplus$, it needs distribute law first

Comment: I think I may have misunderstood your question. Is it about (1) "Once you know the $f_\text{Answer}$, how do you convert $f_\text{Question}$ into $f_\text{Answer}$?", or is it about (2) "I don't even know $f_\text{Answer}$ with the minimal number of operations/gates, help me find it in general case, and prove that it is the same function as $f_\text{Question}$."

Comment: My point for (2) is - to prove that two expressions are equivalent you don't *need* to transform one to another - you just need to check their truth tables. (That means their DNFs are the same, and so the transform from the first one to their common DNF and back to the second one can be done etc. etc., as above.) That is, unless this is a part of some exercise where you are explicitly *asked* to provide the steps.

Comment: Its nearly (2),but a slight change,It's *"I don't even know  with the minimal number of operations/gates, help me find it in general case,* **NOT** *and prove that it is the same function as"*

Comment: The answer for (2) will critically depend on the exact list of gates that you can use and how many inputs they support (e.g. have you got NAND with three inputs?) and I cannot help you much as I don't know of any algorithms for it, except for brute force (try all circuits with 1 gate, all circuits with 2 gates, all circuits with 3 gates etc. sure works - but not so much e.g. in an exam setting!) - checking truth tables along the way until you find the equivalent one.

Comment: 1. ***XOR,NOR,OR,AND,NAND,EXNOR*** are allowed gates, 2. for simplicity lets take ***they accept only 2 inputs***, 3. but we can't try all possibility,as there are  infinite possibility, I accept brute force as I am asking this q.s for computer algorithm... ***but even brute force have infinite possibilities, we can connect infinite gates in any manner,so infinite possibilities(the inputs and allowed types gates are limited,but allowed number of gates is unlimited,so possibilities unlimited,and brute force:impossible)***

Comment: Well, DNF is always a solution and it has however many gates it ends up with (say $n$) so you can restrict yourself to $n$ gates or less. Or, in fact, you can already stop when you reach the number of gates used in $f_\text{Question}$ (in this example $4$)!

Comment: Then what is $n$, if I found the maximum possible unique connections($n$) for a given set of gates and inputs, then I can apply brute force, with the help of a computer.

Comment: As I said, take as $n$ the number of circuits in $f_\text{Question}$. If you can’t beat that, take $f_\text{Answer}=f_\text{Question}$.

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot, can you put this as your answer. It would be enough